# Add leading space to EL variable when it is not empty

Tags: jsp, el

is there a more elegant way to add a leading space when I add a ${parameter} and it exists?

Example:
I want to create a message to the user and depending on the status of my object it might have a serial number or not. but in any way I want to show this text:

```
Should this carrier be removed from it's parent container (${container.name} ${container.serialNumber})?
```

When the serial number exists it looks ok, when the serial number doesn't exist, there is a space between the name and the closing parenthesis.

currently i'd avoid it adding something like `${not empty container.serialNumber?'&nbsp;':''}` before.

This adds more clutter to the code and doesn't necessarily makes it more readable. Another option would be adding the space on the backend site, but that would mix frontend and backend logic.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight improvement might be writing the expression like:

```
${empty container.serialNumber?'':'&nbsp;'}
```

.. but this really calls for a custom EL function. To create one, see the [EL tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

If you don't want to write a custom EL function, you could always add a method to your `container` model to get the formatted string.